# cant push new view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

So I am using a 3rd party lib for scanning barcodes - shopsavvy. What I am trying to do is to show a new screen with all scanned barcode once the scanner is dismissed. I have done (what I thought is pretty straightforward) the following, but not getting the new screen, rather going back to the original screen after the scanner is dismissed.

What am I doing wrong?

This is in my main view controller:

```
- (void) scannerViewController:(SKScannerViewController *)scanner didRecognizeCode:(SKCode *)code {
NSLog(@"didRecognizeCode = %@", code.rawContent);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //We're done scanning barcodes so we should dismiss our modal view controller.

_codeInfoLabel.text = code.rawContent; 

[self showResults:code.rawContent];

}
```

I am getting into this method and its being executed, but nothing happens.

```
 - (void) showResults: (NSString *) barcode {

Results *resultsViewController = [[Results alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
resultsViewController.tempBarcode = barcode;
UINavigationController *resultsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:resultsViewController];
resultsNavigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:resultsNavigationController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: What happens if you just present the resultsViewController instead of adding it to the navigation controller first?

Comment: same thing - nothing happens.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use the `initWithNibName` method unless you have a nib file, but `initWithFrame`instead?

Comment: Can you present _any_ other view controller?

Comment: I dont have any...when the scanner dismisses itself, I go back to the main page (instead of the results page), and there, I can click on "scan" to launch the scanner again - that works.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the line with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`? Does it show up then?

Comment: scanner stays on and nothing happens. this is so frustrating...

Comment: Don't you have to add the NavigationController as a subview to have it shown (like `[[self view] addSubview:[resultsNavigationController view]];`)?

Comment: nop, not here. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get this type of thing to work was to pop back to the original controller when the scanner view was dismissed.

Then, in your "view will appear" check some type of status set in the scanning process, maybe set in prefs, like "scanner complete". If so, launch the results display.

Comment: do you mean in the "view will appear" of the view from which I pushed the scanner? (where the "Scan" button is?). I am not sure I have any indication of that, but sounds in theory the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it makes more sense just to pop straight to the results page rather then dismissing it then loading a new view.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:resultsViewController animated:YES];
```